# How do I search the buffer for nicknames in WeeChat

Tags: irc, weechat

It is normally possible to search within the buffer's messages with the key combination `ctrl-r`. How does one search for a message with a specific sender? For example, the messages sent by the nickname "fooBar".

Answer (score 4):

press ctrl+r press tab and it will toggle threw the different search types

Search indicator ("~": case insensitive, "==": case sensitive, "str": search string, "regex": search regular expression, "msg": search in messages, "pre": search in prefixes, "pre|msg": search in prefixes and messages)

http://weechat.org/files/doc/stable/weechat_user.en.html#key_bindings_search_context